# Alternative to bitmap for android application

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I use a listview of an object. This object contains different attributes and an image.
I get this image by asking the server a jpg image with an http request.
I convert this image into a bitmap and I then display it.

My application is lagging and slow since I have added the bitmaps.
Is there any solution to reduce this lag?

Comment: your solution is to read this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Scale the images down to the size you need

Comment: or is there any simpler way than converting the image into bitmap?

Comment: as tycj mentioned, you can efficiently load the bitmaps that are obtained from a remote source.
You can also take a look at the example from this link, which resizes the images before displaying
http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/

Answer (score 0):

The way I had to solve something similar was to use:

[LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) that stores the images in memory for quick access

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to pull the image from the server, scale it to the needed size, add it into the cache, and use the onProgress to update the ListView image.